# Where can I find information about programming the TI TMS320C64xx DMA controller

Tags: embedded, dma, texas-instruments

I need to do some simple memory transfer using this DSP, but I am unable to find any documentation about the DMA  functions.  I am using C  with code composer 3.3

Comment: did u try using examples given with code composer studio? Those things cover lot more than basics.

Comment: @calvin can you please point to the appropriate files,  there are examples for many kinds of TI DSPs, with my very limited experience in this area I got completely lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that Texas Instruments gives quite some documentation on these processors. For instance, the [TMS320C6418 data sheet](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320c6418.pdf). A list of [all TMS320C64xx controllers is listed here](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=dsp&sectionId=2&tabId=217&familyId=477) (click on the part number to go to the reference material).

I'm not well acquainted with the subject matter, just tried to locate the information for you. If this isn't providing the information you're after, please let me know.

EDIT: added links below for ease of reference for later visitors (they have been mentioned in the comments):

- List of published documents for these and other related Texas Instruments IC's: [Digital Signal Processors & ARM Microprocessors](http://focus.ti.com/dsp/docs/dspcontent.tsp?contentId=1107)
- General reference guide for TMS320C64xx processors: [TMS320C64x+ DSP Megamodule Reference Guide](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru871j/spru871j.pdf)
- Somewhat related, as an example of programming: [video processing with the TMS320C64xx processors](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru871j/spru871j.pdf).

*See also [the answer provided by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011777/where-can-i-find-information-about-programming-the-ti-tms320c64xx-dma-controller/2011926#2011926) himself, which shows two additional helpful documents.*

Comment: thanks, for your efforts ,  unfortunately none of this documents has any information about the actual programming of the DMA

Comment: Have you tried the programming guide for Image/Video processing with the IC: http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru871j/spru871j.pdf (page 139 has a C example). A more general reference guide is here: http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru871j/spru871j.pdf and try this list of documents: http://focus.ti.com/dsp/docs/dspcontent.tsp?contentId=1107. Note "Using C to Access Data Stored in Program Memory on the TMS320C54x™ DSP" (while for another IC, you may find enough info to get going). Nothing here is "simple", but so isn't the subject...

Comment: thanks!  this list (http://focus.ti.com/dsp/docs/dspcontent.tsp?contentId=1107)  is gold, I found the user manual AND  the complete reference, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. I updated the answer to contain the links for ease of reference to later visitors.

Answer (score 4):

OK in a flash of inspiration I Googled for  the  one DMA specific function I found in the code,   and found [this](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ml/sprp567/sprp567.pdf)   and  [TMS320C645x DSP  Enhanced DMA (EDMA3) Controller user Guide](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru966b/spru966b.pdf)

Comment: Seems a good document. There's a lot information out there (see also my comment on my post), but this slide show separates the chaff from wheat for you.